# Spec validate_uniqueness_of test scoped with conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, model, rspec3

I have a model where I'm validating a field conditionally. It looks like this:

```
validates :case_id,
        uniqueness: {
                      scope: :user_id,
                      message: 'Message'
                    },
        unless: Proc.new { |c| c.user_id.nil? }
```

The test I have for it, thus far, looks like this:

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:case_id)
              .scoped_to(:user_id)
              .with_message('Message.') }
```

The problems is I don't know how to incorporate the unless conditional into the test?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can test it in one line, but here is what I'd do:

```
  context 'when user_id is nil' do
    before { subject.stub(:user_id) { nil } }
    it { expect(subject).to_not validate_uniqueness_of(:case_id) }
  end
```

Comment: thanks for that. But what about testing it when user_id is not nil? The test you posted would test for when it's nil but what about when it's not nil? I can't exactly use my existing test to do that as I would get an error because of the ```unless``` conditional. I need a way to combine the tests. Or perhaps there's a way to rewrite the model validation? That seems more complicated?

Comment: what I've posted is an addition to what you already have - add it to your existing specs and it will be the combination you've mentioned above :)

Comment: I can't exactly do just that as my original test above gives me an error   - "Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:case_id)
       Expected errors to include "Message" when case_id is set to 0,
       got no errors" - 
So adding yours will do nothing to correct that. The only way is to somehow incorporate yours into mine as one test. The my question stands.

Comment: @JCC, you have to create another context, `when user_id is not uniq`. In this context you'll have to build 2 instances (be it `Post`). Save post1, and than save post2 with the same `user_id`. Here is where your `expect(subject).to validate_uniqueness_of(:case_id).scoped_to(:user_id).with_message('Message.')` comes in. These 2 contexts should cover your validation

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give you credit even though it's not the exact solution it was helpful in getting me to getting the test to pass. I took your advice about needing to have two separate tests for this single conditional validation. Instead of using just one factory stub I used two to test one with user_id nil and one without. Two stubs and two tests is the solution. Thanks again!